# Error while loading image from file-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack-file-loader

I am facing error while getting same bundled image from different route

While my app is in route `http://localhost:8080`

My image load perfectly from url `http://localhost:8080/3e8b0bc82f581817994bbe9e9396170b.jpg`

But as my app route changed to `http://localhost:8080/dashboard`

My image also loads from url `http://localhost:8080/dashboard/3e8b0bc82f581817994bbe9e9396170b.jpg`

Since the image is at url location `http://localhost:8080/3e8b0bc82f581817994bbe9e9396170b.jpg`
 So it shows `404 resource not found` error while getting the resources from the given location.

I am using  `require('../image.jpg')` to add image in my app.

This is my `webpack.config.js` file.

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react',  "env"]
      }
     },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/i, loader: "file-loader",
        options:{outputPath:'images/'}},
      {test:/\.json?$/,loader:'json-loader'}
  
    ],
    
  },
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './public',
    hot:true
  },
devtool:"cheap-module-eval-source-map"

}
```

I am using webpack version: "^3.1.0".

Comment: May you please load your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: @fshock any idea what am i missing

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Also which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: @fshock i am not able to load image in my app.